# iOS viewDidAppear()でアラート画面を同期的に表示したい。

Tags: swift, ios

viewDidAppear()内でUIAlertControllを使用したアラート画面を表示し、ボタンが押されるまで待つようしたいです。(iOS11)
下記の処理を実装しましたが、アラート画面が表示されず画面のタップもできない状態になります。

非同期や遅延実行によるアラート画面呼び出しは問題なくアラート画面が表示されます。
同期をとる何かいい手段はないでしょうか？

```
override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {

    super.viewDidAppear(animated)

    var doneloop = false

    let alert = UIAlertController(title:"タイトル", message: "メッセージ", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.alert)

    let action1 = UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: UIAlertActionStyle.default, handler: {
        (action: UIAlertAction!) in
        print("push OK button")

        doneloop = true // Runloopを抜ける
    })

    alert.addAction(action1)

    self.present(alert, animated: false, completion: nil)

    // ボタンがクリックされるまで待機
    while !doneloop {
        RunLoop.current.run(until: Date(timeIntervalSinceNow: 0.1))
    }

    alert.dismiss(animated: false, completion: nil)
}
```

Comment: 新規のプロジェクトを作り ( Single View App ) 、記載のコードを貼り付けてみましたが、アラートが正常に表示され、OKもタップできました。上記のコード以外に部分に原因があるのではないでしょうか？

Comment: コメントありがとうございます。発生条件が抜けていました。viewDidAppear()の対象UIViewControllerは、モーダル表示(storyboardでshow接続)されたものでした。

Comment: ご自身で経験されたように、本来非同期の処理を同期的に使うとたとえ`RunLoop`を処理しても条件や状態によりうまく動かないことが多々ありえます。なぜ無理矢理に同期的に使用する必要があるのでしょうか?

Comment: コメントありがとうございます。同期はそのほかにも問題ありそうですね。同期はあきらめるしかなさそうですね。ありがとうございました。